# Server-side processing default order

Tags: php, datatable, datatables

I want to set the default ordering of my datatable into desc.

I tried to see the value of **$request["order"][0]['dir']** it always comes up in ascending order. Is there a way to set the ordering to descending order? I have added my JS below.

```
 $sqlRecord .= " ORDER BY ". $columns[$request['order'][0]['column']] ." " . $request["order"][0]['dir'] . " LIMIT " . $request["start"] . " ," . $request["length"]. " ";

$.ajax({
    url: "coordinator-activities-table.php",
    method: "POST",
    success: function(data){
        $("#retailer-activities-container").html(data);

        table = [
            { "width": "120px", "orderable": false, "targets": 0 },
            { "width": "80px", "targets": 1 },
            { "width": "150px", "targets": 2 },
            { "width": "120px", "targets": 3 },
            { "width": "150px", "targets": 4 },
            { "width": "150px", "targets": 5 },
            { "width": "150px", "targets": 6 },
            { "width": "150px", "targets": 7 },   
            { "width": "150px", "targets": 8 },
            { "width": "150px", "targets": 9 },
            { "width": "120px", "targets": 10 },
            { "width": "100px", "targets": 11 },
            { "width": "110px", "targets": 12 },
            { "width": "110px", "targets": 13 },
            { "width": "150px", "targets": 14 },
            { "width": "150px", "targets": 15 },
            { "width": "120px", "targets": 16 },
            { "width": "150px", "orderable": false, "targets": 17 }
        ];

        var table = $('#activities-table').DataTable({
            "searching": { "regex": true },
            "paging": true,
            "autoWidth": false,
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax": {
                url: "coordinator-activities-data.php",
                type: "POST",
                "dataType": "json",
                data: {coordinator:coordinator, startdate:startdate, enddate:enddate, regional:regional},
                "complete": function(response) {
                }
            },
            "columnDefs": table,
            "language": {
                "emptyTable": "No data available in table",
                "zeroRecords": "No data available in table",
                "info": "Showing <b>_START_</b> to <b>_END_ of _TOTAL_</b> entries",
                "paginate": {
                    "first":      "First",
                    "last":       "Last",
                    "next":       "Next",
                    "previous":   "Previous"
                },
                search: "_INPUT_",
                searchPlaceholder: "Search..."
            },
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            buttons: [
                'csv', 'excel', 'pdf'
            ]
        });
    },
    error: function(data){
        console.log("error");
    }
});
```

I want to set the default ordering to descending

Comment: `ORDER BY ... DESC`, at least in MySql.

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone when the datatable is loaded the order should be descending order but I can still click the sorting

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone I am using datatables serverside processing

Comment: What code is sending the request?

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone I want to change the value of $request["order"][0]['dir'] into Descending right now when I get the value of $request["order"][0]['dir'] the value is "ASC"

Comment: Of course you could set the value to "DESC", however, the isue seems to be that the request sends "ASC". Not clear what you are asking. Without seeing the sending code, nobody can guess why it always sends "ASC".

Comment: @LawrenceAgulto do you want the first request the datatable makes to be in DESC or you want to change every request to DESC?

Comment: @shubham I want the first request to be DESC

Comment: @LawrenceAgulto check my edited answer.

Comment: @shubham I added my js please see updated question

Answer (score 0):

You can change the Sort data when datatable makes the request to server like this :

```
        var firstsort='DESC';

                var table = $('#activities-table').DataTable({
                    "searching": { "regex": true },
                    "paging": true,
                    "autoWidth": false,
                    "processing": true,
                    "serverSide": true,
                    "ajax": {
                        url: "coordinator-activities-data.php",
                        type: "POST",
                        "dataType": "json",
                        data: function (data) {

                            var sort = data.order[0].column;
                            //check condition or remove condition if you want every request with sort DESC
                            if (firstsort != '') {
                                data.order[0].dir = "DESC";
                                firstsort = '';
                            }
                            data['coordinator'] = coordinator, data['regional'] = regional,
                                data['startdate'] = startdate, data['enddate'] = enddate;

                            return data;
                        },
                        "complete": function (response) {
                        }
                    },
                    "columnDefs": table,
                    "language": {
                        "emptyTable": "No data available in table",
                        "zeroRecords": "No data available in table",
                        "info": "Showing <b>_START_</b> to <b>_END_ of _TOTAL_</b> entries",
                        "paginate": {
                            "first": "First",
                            "last": "Last",
                            "next": "Next",
                            "previous": "Previous"
                        },
                        search: "_INPUT_",
                        searchPlaceholder: "Search..."
                    },
                    dom: 'Bfrtip',
                    buttons: [
                        'csv', 'excel', 'pdf'
                    ]
                });
```

Comment: It is not working for me. Is there a way to edit it in PHP?

Comment: I added it please see

Comment: @LawrenceAgulto try this, I've changed in your code only.